# Inputting a function into frameticks with ArrayPlot

Tags: plotting, output-formatting

Here's some data:

`data={{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{3,4,5}}`

Here's the data plotted:

`ArrayPlot[data,FrameTicks->Automatic]`

[image]

I want to modify the frame ticks such that the horizontal axis is `{Sin[2],Sin[3],Sin[4]}` and the vertical axis is `{0.3,0.6,0.9}`. How can I do this?

The documentation on [FrameTicks](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html) suggests that I should define a function and input that. However, I can't parse the example given. What are the arguments passed to the function when used in this way? Naively I'd guess that it's just the index of the x- and y- arrays (so e.g. {1,1} would be the top-left box), but attempting to write my own function, e.g. with `xaxis[min_,max_]:=min+1` and `yaxis[min_,max_]:=min+2`, doesn't work. `ArrayPlot[data,FrameTicks->{xaxis,yaxis}]` leads to an ArrayPlot with no frame ticks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** For arbitrary tick labels

```
hticklabels = {Sin[2], Sin[3], Sin[4]} ;
vticklabels = {0.3, 0.6, .9};

{hticks, vticks} = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, #] & /@ {hticklabels, vticklabels};

ArrayPlot[data, FrameTicks -> {{vticks, vticks}, {hticks, hticks}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use

```
{hticks, vticks} = Transpose[{Range@Length@#, #}] & /@ {hticklabels, vticklabels}
```

**Original answer:**

You can use the option [`DataRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html):

```
ArrayPlot[data, FrameTicks -> Automatic, DataRange -> {{2, 4}, {3, 5}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ArrayPlot[data, 
 FrameTicks -> {{#, #} & @ Thread[{Range[3], 1 + Range[3]}],
   {#, #} & @ Thread[{Range[3], 2 + Range[3]}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I think I simplified my minimal working example too much ... going to edit the question.

Comment: @Allure, please see the update.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of an exposition to kglr's answer, which works, but is also a bit hard to parse.

`FrameTicks` is looking for input of the form {{1,[func]},{2,[func]},{3,[func]}}, where [func] is the function you want. Therefore one can manually set the horizontal labels to be {{1,Sin[2]},{2,Sin[3]},{3,Sin[4]}}. The `MapIndexed` command as used by kglr is a fancy way of generating this list.

You can also try something like

`vticklabels = Range[0.3,0.9,0.3]` (generates a list from 0.3 to 0.9 in steps of 0.3, see the documentation on `Range`) followed by

`vticks = MapIndexed[{First[#2], #} &, vticklabels]` (First[#2] is the index of the argument - 1,2,3, etc. & puts the elements of vticklabels into the corresponding slot. This generates the list {{1,0.3},{2,0.6},{3,0.9}} which is the list to give FrameTicks)

FrameTicks accepts up to four arguments. In the command `FrameTicks -> {a,b,c,d}`, the list in `a` goes on the left-hand vertical axis of the frame, `b` goes into the bottom horizontal axis of the frame, `c` goes to the right-hand vertical axis, and `d` goes to the top horizontal axis.